# Make doesn't find my .so.2.4.8 files

Tags: c++, opencv, makefile, cmake

I am trying to compile a C++ program that uses OpenCV. My CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( DisplayImage )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
add_executable( main main.cpp )
target_link_libraries( main ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

However, when running make I get the following error:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/path/to/folder/opencv/lib/libopencv_contrib.so', needed by `main'.  Stop.
```

The reason is obvious: the .so files exist as .so.2.4.8 (where 2.4.8 is the OpenCV version) and not .so files, so make doesn't find them. How do I tell cmake to generate a makefile that uses the .so.2.4.8 files and not .so files?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you link to an unversioned library that is a symbolic link to the versioned one.

In other words, you need a symlink (which is normally installed by the `-devel` package along with the header files):

```
.../libopencv_contrib.so -> .../libopencv_contrib.so.2.4.8
```

Another way is to link it as `-l:libopencv_contrib.so.2.4.8` instead of `-lopencv_contrib`.

Comment: Is there no other way? OpenCV doesn't generate the .so symlinks automatically when compiled, for whatever reason.

Comment: @Aqwis Added another way for you.